# Why don't we see more Aurors using Disillusionment Charms, Muffliato or similar protective enchantments when hunting down Dark Wizards?

Tags: harry-potter

Why don't we see more Aurors using Disillusionment Charms, Muffliato or similar protective enchantments when hunting down Dark Wizards?

Aren't the Disillusionment Charms and Muffliato spells that fall under "Concealment and Disguise" and "Stealth and Tracking", which is part of the Auror training under the Ministry of Magic? Surely, they would have had higher chances of winning and capturing Dark Wizards if they were concealing not only their appearance but also the sounds that they make.

Using these two charms would have been useful during both the First and Second Wizarding Wars against Voldemort and his dark forces, as well as the Global Wizarding War against Grindelwald and his forces.

Comment: How often do we see Aurors doing anything?

Comment: @Alex You should make that an answer. The only time Harry sees aurors doing anything it is when acting as personal bodyguards. Every other reference is third- person gossip.

Comment: You know, that "Muffliato" is a spell invented by the Half Blood Prince and therefor not commonly known?

Comment: I recommend changing the title to: "Do Aurors use Disillusionment Charms or similar protective enchantments when hunting down Dark Wizards?"

Comment: Agree. Because otherwise the answer is: because Harry does not see them and the story is told from his perspective...

Answer (score 1):

Who says they don't? The books are written from Harry's POV, and he is very uninformed and uncaring of these details. Even if he does know, it is never mentioned. But, no where is it said they don't use them or use them scarcely.